# Meal Generator Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, syntax-error, system

I have been working on this code for some time. It keeps saying this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "N:\Computing\Meal Generator.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(DaysOfTheWeek[0+counter],": ",Meals[random_meal]," and a number of ",NumberOfSides[random_meal],".")

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Here is the code which is displaying this error any help will be greatful.

```
import random
random.seed()


Meals=[]
SideDishes=[]
DaysOfTheWeek=["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"]
print("1=Meal, 2=Side, 3=Finished")
option=input("What would you like to do?: ")
while option!=3:
    if option=="1":
        MealName=input("What meal would you like to add?: ")
        NumberOfSides=input("How many sides would you like have with the meal?: ")
        Meals=Meals,MealName,NumberOfSides
    if option=="2":
        SideName=input("What side would you like to add?: ")
        SideDishes+=SideName
    print("1=Meal, 2=Side, 3=Finished")
    try_again=input("What else would you like to do?: ")
    if try_again=="1":
        option="1"
    elif try_again=="2":
        option="2"
    else:
        break
print("Printing out meals for you")
counter=1
for counter in DaysOfTheWeek:
    random_meal=random.randint(0,len(Meals)-1)
    random_side=random.randint(0,len(SideDishes)-1)
    print(DaysOfTheWeek[0+counter],": ",Meals[random_meal]," and a number of ",NumberOfSides[random_meal],".")
    print("And the the side that will be served with will be: ",SideDishes[random_side])
    counter+=1
print("Thanks for using the Meal-O-Matic")
```

Thanks for your help.
Tinymantwo

Comment: Have you *read* the error message? It's telling you that `counter` is a `str`, and therefore `0+counter` makes no sense. You are looping over a list of strings, so e.g. `counter == "Mon"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misunderstood how for loops work in Python.

When you do `for counter in DaysOfTheWeek`, `counter` takes in turn each value from `DaysOfTheWeek`. That means the first time it will be "Mon", then "Tue", etc. So when you try to add it to 0, it fails with that error.

But you shouldn't be adding it to anything: that's the point. Instead, do this:

```
for day in DaysOfTheWeek:
    ...
    print(day, ": ", Meals[random_meal]," and a number of ",NumberOfSides[random_meal],".")
```

and you don't need `counter=0` or `counter+=1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python like a Javascript programmer :)

Please read up on how this stuff works for Python, a few hints:

- `for counter in ["asdf", "bla"]` iterates over the *entries*  of the list, not the list indices, so `counter` will be `"asdf"` and `"bla"`
- `input` returns a string, so `while option != 3` won't help you much